# What is the naming convention for the JOINing resources?

Tags: api, rest

Two resources:

- `/user`
- `/product`

The database table name is `user_product` and it describes relation between user and product. However, endpoint `POST /user/{id}/product/{id}` would indicate updating a specific `product` under `user`, as opposed to creating a new relation.

I have therefore named the resource `POST /user/{id}/product/{id}/purchase`, which defines fictional resource purchase. After all, this is what the data in the table represents.

I am aware that the original [dissertation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) describing REST principles does little to standardise naming. I'd like to know what are industry established conventions for naming resource that identifies a relationship between two resources?

Comment: Consider `/purchases/{userId}/{productId}` as another option.

Comment: I think it is better to turn the relation to an entity, so you can expose the purchase resource as Dai suggest with its own id (not a composite id), or not exposing the relation in an endpoint at all (meaning, you update the collection of products under the user using your first url sample, or vice versa).

Comment: I don't understand the validity of @Dai suggestion. This creates ambiguity. What would `/purchases/{X}` refer to? `{purchase}` or `{user}`? Plus, this will require user to remember order of parameters: it easy to accidentally mistake it for `/purchases/{productId}/{userId}`. However, I could name the resource `/user_product`. That would address at least the last of these issues.

Comment: I thought about this a bit more.. It does not seem to work. If `/user_product/{id}` refers to a specific relation, then how would I get all user products? Would it be `/user/{id}/user_product`?

Comment: @GajusKuizinas Given that APIs should be rigidly documented, that a resource-path is not self-describing does not mean it is ambiguous. Your service would only accept lookups of the form `/purchases/{userId}/{productId}` (using the two IDs as the resource's composite key). Finally, RESTful APIs are consumed by clients, not humans (at least not generally), so worrying about ambiguity in the order of parameters is not a legitimate concern in my book.

Comment: @Dai  APIs should be self documenting. /something/{id1}/{id2} is bad practice at best, the url is definetly not restfull.

Comment: I am playing around with the names and how they fit in with the rest of the docs. So far my favourite is `POST /user/{id}/product/{id}/user_product` to create a new `user_product`. Where `GET|UPDATE /user_product/{id}` can be used to access a specific  `user_product` (alias of `/user/{id}/product/{id}/user_product/{id}`).

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your purchase is stored in a database somewhere and the actual purchase assigned its own ID. Why not use that ID directly as in `/purchases/{purchase-id}`?

Your example `/user/{id}/product/{id}/purchase` won't work if one user has more than one purchase of the same product. Unless of course the resource either signals "The user has at least one purchase of product X" or returns a list of all purchases of product X for that user - which looks more like a query (which is fine to assign its own resource).

> I have therefore named the resource `POST /user/{id}/product/{id}/purchase`.

Please be aware that you don't include method names (like POST) in resource names. And why the POST? Is it for creating/modifying the relation - or did you mean GET to get some information about the relation?

> I am aware that the original dissertation describing REST principles does little to standardise naming. I'd like to know what are industry established conventions for naming resource that identifies a relationship between two resources?

No, but if you want some hints then I wrote a piece on this subject here: http://soabits.blogspot.dk/2013/10/url-structures-and-hyper-media-for-web.html